# Applying Hash Function n times

Tags: c, hash

I need to implement the iterative aplication of the certain hash function for example SHA1 with input x n times, efficiently, i.e SHA1(...SHA1(SHA1(x))). I'm trying to make this with the code below but this so slow 2 sec for n=2^16. In the code below $n$ is the number of times to apply SHA1, x=seedj1 and temp=SHA1(...SHA1(SHA1(x))). Could yo help me please?

```
int hashcwe_n1(int n, unsigned char * seedj1, unsigned char * temp) {
int i, j;
int r = 160;
memcpy(temp, seedj1, r);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    SHA1(seedj1, r, temp);
    if (n % 2 != 0)
        swapStrings(&temp, &seedj1);
    else {
        if (i == n - 1) {
            memcpy(seedj1, R, r);
        } else {
         swapStrings(&temp, &seedj1);
        }
    }
}
return 1;
}

void swapStrings(unsigned char** a, unsigned char** b) {
unsigned char *temp = *a;
*a = *b;
*b = temp;
}
```

Comment: Optimization aside, your code looks suspiciously wrong. SHA1 produces 160 bits, but it seems like your arrays are of length 160 bytes. Also, you're copying `R` into the `seedj1` at the end, but there's no `R` in this code. Does it even run correctly?

Comment: swapString() only changes the pointers (which were passed by value in C) in the copies of the pointers in the parameter list for the hashcwe_n1() function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't believe you're algorithm is even correct, so measuring its performance is somewhat akin to counting chickens before the hens lay the eggs, much less before the eggs hatch.

There is no reason the iterative workload function should exhibit such abysmal performance unless...

- Your SHA implementation is hideously inefficient
- Your test rig was made when Windows 3.11 was new and exciting.

The following is a jig that should be correct, and exhibits acceptable performance (in my opinion, at least). The relevant data for the test machine used:

- MacBook Air (2011), Intel Core i7 Duo, 4GB 1333mhz RAM
- Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)
- OpenSSL libcrypto ver 0.9.8zd 8 Jan 2015

**The Source**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <openssl/sha.h>

// simple hex-print utility
void hex_print(const void *buf, size_t n)
{
    const unsigned char *beg = buf, *end = beg+n;
    while (beg != end)
        printf("%02x", *beg++);
    fputc('\n', stdout);
}


// iterate n-times
void hashcwe_n
(
    unsigned short n,   // iteration count
    void *src,          // source bytes
    size_t slen,        // souce length
    void *dst           // target buffer
)
{
    unsigned char md1[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char md2[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    unsigned char *p1 = md1, *p2 = md2;
    unsigned short i;

    if (n == 0)
        return;

    // perform initial digest
    SHA1(src, slen, md1);

    // iterate the remainder of the loop
    for (i=0; i<(n-1); ++i)
    {
        unsigned char *tmp = p1;
        SHA1(p1, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH, p2);
        p1 = p2;
        p2 = tmp;
    }
    memcpy(dst, p1, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);
}

// main entry point
int main()
{
    unsigned char data[] = {0x61,0x62,0x63}; // "abc"
    unsigned char md[SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};

    hashcwe_n(USHRT_MAX, data, sizeof(data), md);
    hex_print(md, SHA_DIGEST_LENGTH);

    return 0;
}
```

**Build Command**

```
clang -std=c11 -O2 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -lcrypto -o sample sample.c
```

**Output Console**

```
$ time ./sample
a21b4b42e20066a1046d3c81b42b7cd8a6403bf2

real  0m0.031s
user  0m0.026s
sys   0m0.003s
```

[See here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/fc903b583c4ce644) for the same sample run live on Coliru.

Best of luck

Comment: Old AMD Turion Dual Core - `real 0.066s, user 0.055s, sys 0.005s`, for grins an old Athlon T-Bird 800 MHz (`0.099, 0.096s, 0.004s`). I'd say performance is much more than just acceptable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin That's really throwing down the gauntlet. Now I feel compelled to head to the attic and see if I can find my old AMD K-5 PR166, or even my old DX33. Or just throw it on my RPi. Thanks for the test run, btw.

Comment: Oh lord! I still have one box running SuSE 8.0 pro (that I didn't fire up) that is about as ancient as the other old AMD K-5 I used as a backup (spinning dual 20G drives), until just a year or so ago. With the quality of the capacitors, etc. in the old boxes, they will probably run for another 10 years. I still have the Athlon 800 in use as a production machine (hylafax/avantfax fax server that I built in 2001, sheeze I'm getting old...).